# Loop with non-repeated fields

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I just started using advanced custom fields and it is awesome. I have been struggling with this one issues and I would love some help with it.

I have setup a product name, price and image field under the products field group. I have it working so it shows the information on the product page but I have no clue how to do the loop for the overview of all products (i.e. I want to make a page that has all the products on it).

```
<?php if(get_field('products')): ?>
<?php the_sub_field('product-name');?>
<?php the_sub_field('product-price');?>
<?php the_sub_field('product-image');?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Is anyone on the interweb able to help me out and give me a quick lesson on advanced custom fields looping? I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a field for a custom post type?

If so, you just need to do a WordPress loop.

```
<?php
    // Loop through custom post type
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'YOURPOSTTYPE', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        if(get_field('products')) : 
            the_sub_field('product-name');
            the_sub_field('product-price');
            the_sub_field('product-image');
        endif;

    endwhile;
?>
```